# Can Seam persistence be used in a standalone app (outside any web container)

Tags: java, seam, cdi, weld

Can Seam persistence (http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/PersistenceModule) be used in a standalone weld powered application? Standalone means an application outside of any web container; just a simple Java application.

I guess the answer is theoretically yes, but I'm afraid they are dependencies lurking in the dark (Servlet / Java EE / etc).

We are using with great satisfaction Weld in our standalone application, and I try to figure out if Seam persistence can be used.

I did not find any documentation validating / invalidating this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it can. I went back and forth with someone for quite some time who was trying to get it to work and nothing worked out for him. Take a look at DeltaSpike though, I'm sure there's something there that will fill what you're looking for.